# AWS Amplify Auth - Error when fetching user attributes of a signed in user

Tags: android, aws-amplify

I'm trying to use `AWS Amplify Auth` in my `Android` App. Sign Up and Sign In works, now I'm trying to fetch the User Attributes of the signed in user, but Amplify throws an exception in the `Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes()` function.

My sign in code:

```
private void login(String email, String password) {
        Amplify.Auth.signIn(
                email,
                password,
                result -> {
                    if (result.isSignInComplete()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Sign in succeeded");
                        Log.i(TAG, "going to fetch User attributes");
                        
                            Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes(
                                    attributes -> Log.i("AuthDemo", "User attributes = " + attributes.toString()),
                                    error -> Log.e("AuthDemo", "Failed to fetch user attributes.", error)
                            );

                        Log.i(TAG, "end of fetching User attributes");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG,  "Sign in not complete");
                    }

                },
                error -> Log.e(TAG, error.toString())
        );
    }
```

The log:

```
I/LoginActivity: Sign in succeeded
W/InternalCallback: Library attempted to call user callback twice, expected only once
I/LoginActivity: going to fetch User attributes
D/AWSMobileClient: Inspecting user state details
D/AWSMobileClient: waitForSignIn: userState:SIGNED_OUT
E/AuthDemo: Failed to fetch user attributes.
    AuthException{message=Failed to fetch user attributes, cause=java.lang.Exception: Operation requires a signed-in state, recoverySuggestion=Ensure that you are logged in and online}
        at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthPlugin$15.onError(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.java:736)
        ....
     Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Operation requires a signed-in state
        ...
```

It tells me that the User state is: SIGNED_OUT, but I'm calling it inside the successful sign in method, so why is the user signed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if your identity poolId is correct (even if you're not using a guest access) in app -> src -> res -> raw -> `amplifyconfiguration.json` & `awsconfiguration.json`. You can find your poolId in your AWS console -> cognito -> manage identity pools -> click on your pool -> click on Sample code:

[image]